# Merge two list as values inside dictionary based on key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionary that contain list array as value like this :

```
d1 = {'1':[12,32,44,12,34],'2':[21,34,11,65],'3':[44,12,98],'4':[65,71]}
d2 = {'1':[15,11,44,42,14],'2':[11,24,41,65]:'3':[41,22,48]}
```

How can i merge both dictionary into one dictionary based on their similar key, so the answer will be like this:

```
d3 = {'1':[12,32,44,12,34,15,11,44,42,14],'2':[21,34,11,65,11,24,41,65],'3':[44,12,98,41,22,48],'4':[65,71]}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get all the keys using a set union `d1.keys() | d2.keys()`, then it's a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: d1.get(k, []) + d2.get(k, []) for k in (d1.keys() | d2.keys())}
{'1': [12, 32, 44, 12, 34, 15, 11, 44, 42, 14],
 '2': [21, 34, 11, 65, 11, 24, 41, 65],
 '3': [44, 12, 98, 41, 22, 48],
 '4': [65, 71]}
```

*Note:* If you get `TypeError` then you're using an older version of Python.  You can just change `.keys()` to `.viewkeys()` to make it work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [@wim's dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42265284/21945) you could use a `defaultdict` of lists, extending each value while iterating over the input dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for d in d1, d2:
    for k in d:
        result[k].extend(d[k])
```

If desired you can convert `result` back to a standard dict:

```
result = dict(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `defaultdict` of list and `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

d3 = defaultdict(list)
for k, val in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
    d3[k] = d3[k] + val
```